# Firebase first_open event becomes slow

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Firebase first_open event has become slow since the last week. Firebase says that "conversion events are uploaded immediately by the SDK in order to make them actionable more quickly" So, I expect the data will be more or less immediately sent down from the app when the user triggers it or when the app is in background, but it becomes obviously slow these days.

- Viewed on Sep 07, there were 423 first_open on Sep 06.
- Viewed on Sep 08, there were 1306 first_open on Sep 06.
- Viewed on Sep 09, there were 0 first_open on Sep 08.
- Viewed on Sep 12, there were 1092 first_open on Sep 08.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it takes about 24 hours for it to show up in the console. Note that analytics data has a possibility to arrive late because of the variability of network conditions. Analytics data is stored locally in the device, online or offline. When network connection becomes available, Firebase will batch the data and will attempt to upload it. As such, Firebase collect and process events that might arrive up to 3 days late. As a result, metrics for the last 3 days are in a state of flux until 3 days have elapsed. The data for yesterday and today might not have been reflected yet in the console. You could check this [Firebase blog](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up) to know more about the delay in Analytics reporting.